# Ruby on Rails server not reflecting changes to database records until restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-activerecord

If I open the Rails Console and create a new Widget:

```
>> widget = Widget.new
>> widget.name = "Whatever"
>> widget.save
```

The Widget saves without errors.  However, when I run:

```
>> Widget.all
```

This new Widget does not appear in the returned list of records.  However, if I restart the Rails Console and run the same command again:

```
>> Widget.all
```

The Widget now appears in the list of records.  Why is this happening?  I'm having the same problem with the Rails Server; if I create or edit a Widget with the scaffold views I generated, those Widgets do not appear in the show view until I restart the Rails Server.

By the way, I'm on Windows 7, using RubyMine as my IDE, and using rails 3.2.4 and sqlite3.

Comment: Please provide info about your Database sytem

Comment: By the way, I'm on Windows 7, using RubyMine as my IDE, and using rails 3.2.4 and sqlite3.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you should update to rails 3.2.11 immediately. 3.2.4 contains known security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Can you try `puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM widgets")` in your console?

Comment: Okay, I don't know why, but updating to rails 3.2.11 (per Daniel's advice above) and running bundle update has now stopped this phenomenon from happening.  So, thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

One of the commenters above recommended I update to rails 3.2.11.  I updated the version in my Gemfile and ran `bundle update` and this fixed the issue.  I don't know which gem or combination of them was the problem before the update.

Comment: Rails 3.2.4 had a regression that accidentally cached calls to .all